# how to assign a string value associated with an image to a textwidget when image is clicked

Tags: android, android-widget

```
    package com.me.trial;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class TrialActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            img.setClickable(true);
            OnClickListener l;

        }

        private void hasBeenClicked(<method invoked when the user has clicked>){


        }
    }






<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp" >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:tag="Employee name"
                android:src="@drawable/img18" />




            </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I need the application to pass some string value associated to it to be passed into the text as soon as the user clicks on the image.How do i use the click Listeners in android to achieve the following task.
It is not necessary to fill in the code snippet that i have given.Any new ideas regarding the design are most welcome.

Comment: Please clarify the : passed into the text, do you mean the textview?

Comment: No,I mean if there is a string value associated with the image how do i put it into the EditText so that the user need not type anything on the EditText, the text attribute will get automatically filled by the string value associted with the image as soon as it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

U can set text as  `Tag` to the Image so that u can get that text onClick event. `Tag` can be set either in XML or dynamically.

```
public class TrialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setTag("YOur text");
        img.setClickable(true);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   String urText= arg0.getTag().toString(); 
                   EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                   edt.setText(urText);
        }
      });      
    }
}
```

This code demonstrates how to achieve your requirement dynamically.